# WebGL not displaying content

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

i am mainly developing in C++ and decided to compile one of my projects to WebAssembly and build a website upon it. Since I have written some 3D-Engine in C++ before, I decided to use WebGL on the website. I have translated my shader template class. I have reduced the problem to a two-dimensional problem.

---

## Task

First, I will describe what I am trying to do.
I am going to render a 2D FEM-grid which consists of FEM-elements which is any type of polygon. The nodes of those polygons contain values which I am trying to display. I already wrote code to break the polygons down to triangles. Initially I am just trying to render **two dimensional triangles** with their **node values being interpolated**.

---

## Shader Code

I wrote some template shader class in WebGL which handles the construction and compilation of the shaders and has been copied from my C++ 3D-Engine. Since the code itself is somewhat long, I am not going to post it here but eventually show a list of executed OpenGL commands.
The shaders I am currently using to debug my problem are the following:

```cpp
Vertex-Shader:

precision mediump float;
attribute vec2 position;
            
varying vec2 fragPos;
void main(){
   gl_Position = vec4(position,0,1.0);
   fragPos     = position;
}
            
---------------------------------------------------------------

Fragment-Shader:

precision mediump float;
varying vec2 fragPos;
            
uniform sampler2D elementValues;
uniform int elementValuesDimension;
            
void main(){
    gl_FragColor  = vec4(0.8,0.2,0.0,1.0);
}
```

As you can see, I am not going for any interpolation in this debug case but just trying to some red-ish color within my fragment shader.

---

## Executed Commands

I went ahead and used webgl-debug.js to show all the operations done. For this case, you can see the vertices and indices matching a simple quad spanning `[0,0.6]x[0,0.6]` which should be well within the clip space.

This can be broken into a few parts:

1. Enable uint32 as indexing

```cpp
gl.getExtension(OES_element_index_uint)
```

2. Create two buffers for vertex coordinates and indices

```cpp
gl.createBuffer()
gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, [object WebGLBuffer])
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,1,2,0,2,3, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, [object WebGLBuffer])
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,0,0,0.6000000238418579,0.6000000238418579,0.6000000238418579,0.6000000238418579,0, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

3. Create and compile the shaders

```cpp
gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
gl.shaderSource(vertex_shader_src);
gl.compileShader([object WebGLShader]);
gl.getShaderParameter([object WebGLShader], gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragment_shader_src);
gl.compileShader([object WebGLShader]);
gl.getShaderParameter([object WebGLShader], gl.COMPILE_STATUS);

gl.createProgram()

gl.attachShader([object WebGLProgram], [object WebGLShader])
gl.attachShader([object WebGLProgram], [object WebGLShader])
gl.linkProgram([object WebGLProgram])
gl.validateProgram([object WebGLProgram])
```

4. Get Locations of the uniforms (which are unused) as well as the location of the attribute

```cpp
gl.getUniformLocation([object WebGLProgram], elementValues)
gl.getUniformLocation([object WebGLProgram], elementValuesDimension)
gl.getAttribLocation([object WebGLProgram], position)
```

5. Verify that linking has worked

```cpp
gl.getProgramParameter([object WebGLProgram], gl.LINK_STATUS)
```

6. Main Rendering Loop. Initially clear the displayed stuff

```cpp
gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE)
gl.viewport(0, 0, 700, 600)
```

7. Activate the shader and bind the buffers

```cpp
gl.useProgram([object WebGLProgram])
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, [object WebGLBuffer])
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, [object WebGLBuffer])
```

8. Connect the vertices to the first attribute

```cpp
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
```

9. Render Call.

```cpp
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 4, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
```

Sadly when the commands above are executed, I am unable to see anything except a gray screen:

[image]

I am very happy for any help!

Greetings
Finn

Comment: It looks like you have 6 vertices in your indexed vertices `gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,1,2,0,2,3, gl.STATIC_DRAW)` but you're only drawing 4 `gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 4, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, 0)` for maybe there's a mismatch? Can you try `gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, 0)`?

Comment: you are right. that is incorrect. A second problem which I found earlier this day was that I am missing gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);. Now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to teddybeard and a lot more time on this problem spent than I was hoping, two issues have shown up:

1. `l.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,1,2,0,2,3, gl.STATIC_DRAW)` contains 6 vertices but the `drawElements` command only took 4 values. This is obviously a bug but should still have rendered atleast one of the two triangles.
2. Secondly, I forgot to enable the vertex attribute in the shader. `gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);` solved the problem.

Comment: Great! I'm not quite sure why `enableVertexAttribArray(1)` works. In my experience you grab a reference to the program `attribute` and pass that to `enableVerexAttribArray`. i.e.  `const aPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position'); gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);`

Comment: uh thats interesting and seems more reasonable to me too. I am not looking at my pc right now but i think i loaded some uniform to that attribute and set that to 1.

Comment: I checked. So you are right. Your solution is definetely the prettier one but luckily for me the attributes in the vertex shader are numerated beginning from 0. So my vertex coordinates are always in attribArray=0. I did write attribArray(1) above by mistake since I have the coordinates and some vertex values and copied the wrong command.